# Display long text on a panel without slider

Tags: html, css, office-ui-fabric

How do I display a long text in a Panel without a slider? Currently this is how the text is displayed:

[image]

Here the user has to move the slider to see the remaining text. Instead, how can I display the remaining text within view?

I tried using textarea as follows:

```
<textarea rows={5} cols={45}>{value}</textarea>
```

That's displaying an additional slider:

[image]

Comment: the other way is to assign height and width to the textarea and it will be able to show the entire text. But you will have to scroll once the text size increases certain limit

Answer (score 0):

CSS `max-width: 400px; max-height: 1000px;`
Try too  `resize: none;`
If u want text cant edit  `<textarea .. readonly></textarea>`

Comment: didn't work. I'm not able to use readonly and textarea is resizable even after adding the property  resize: none;

Comment: @user3693060   Add this in CSS textarea {height:500px;}   or 600 px just save and see